# drupal 9 form data shoub reflect to people after submission

Tags: php, drupal-modules, autologin, drupal-9, multiple-users

Drupal 9's automatic login following a successful registration means that after the submission of a custom form's data, users should be added. Could someone please give me an example of the code for this? Drupal 9's automatic login following a successful registration means that after the submission of a custom form's data, users should be added. Could someone please give me an example of the code for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: solved with login redirect module thank you